# vscode command line : open a file of an opened project

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a project opened in vscode.

I Windows Powershell, under project directory, when I type

```
code test.html
```

It will open the file but with a new vscode instance, I want in the already opened project instead : is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the `-r` (`--reuse-window`) option.
For example:

```
code -r .\Dockerfile
```

(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

Comment: If you're using the PowerShell integrated terminal within vscode you can also use `psedit file.txt`

Comment: psedit is an alias for Open-EditorFile, and is definitely better than using -r, which reloads the window, interrupting whatever else you might be working on.